# Variable stops being updated and passed to view

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

When I am uploading file to server using form, the action fails. However, I am unable to display the error message because the errors are not being passed on.

The two controller functions are

```
public function update_image()
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
   $data['page'] = 'Profiilikuva';  
   $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
   $this->load->view('templates/user/navbar', $data);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
   $this->load->view('pages/user/upload_image', $data);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
   $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
}                         

public function upload_image()
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
      $data['breakpoint'] = 'Alku';                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      $data['page'] = 'Profiilikuva';                                                                                                                                            
      $config['upload_path']   = './images/profile';
      $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
      $config['max_size']      = 100;
      $config['max_width']      = 1024;
      $config['max_height']    = 768;
      $this->load->library('upload', $config);

      $data['breakpoint'] = 'Kirjasto';
      $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
      $data['breakpoint'] = 'Navigointi Alku';                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
      $this->load->view('templates/student/navbar', $data);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
      $data['breakpoint'] = 'Navigointi Valmis';                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
      if ( $this->upload->do_upload('profileimage') )
      {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
          $data['breakpoint'] = 'Latausvirhe';                                                                                                                                           
          $data['db_error'] = 'Ei Virheitä';                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
          $data['file_error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
          $this->load->view('pages/error', $data);
      }
      else
      {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
          $data['breakpoint'] = 'Lataussuoritettu';                                                                                                                                          
          $where = array('userid' => $this->session->user->userdata->userid);

          $values = array(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
            'profileimage'   => $this->upload->data('file_name') 
          );                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
          if($this->user->update($where, $values) )
          {
              $this->load->view('pages/user/success');                                                                                                 

          }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
          else                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
          {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
              $data['breakpoint'] = 'Tietokanta';                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
              $e = $this->db->error();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
              $data['db_error'] = $e['message'];                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
               $data['file_error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
               $this->load->view('pages/error');                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
          }                   
      }


     $data['breakpoint'] = 'Loppu';                                                                                                                                          
     $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

Now, the error page itself looks like this:

```
<div id="main">
          <div class="content">¨
              <h2> Tapahtui virhe.</h2>
              <p>
                   Virheen tiedot ovat alla. Jos virhe toistuu, ota yhteyttä ylläpitoon. <?php echo $breakpoint; ?> <br />
              </p>
                  <p>
                        <h3>Tietokanta virheet:</h3>
                        <?php echo $db_error; ?>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                       <h3>Tiedostovirheet</h3>
                      <?php echo $file_error; ?>
                  </p>
                  <p>                   
                        <a class="action" href="<?php echo base_url('Userpanel');?>">Palaa profiilin</a> <br />
                  </p>  
          </div>
</div>
```

and the form itself:

```
<div id="main">
   <div class="content">
       <h2>Lataa profiilikuva</h2>
    <p>
       <?php echo form_error(); ?>
    </p>
    <p>
       <?php  
           echo form_open_multipart('Userpanel/upload_image');
           echo form_fieldset('Kuva');  
           echo form_upload('profileimage');                                                                                                                                      
           echo form_fieldset_close();                                                                                                                                                  
           echo form_close();?>
          </div>
          <div class="controls">
            <a class="action" href="<?php echo base_url('Userpanel');?>">Peruuta</a> <br /> 
          </div>
</div>
```

NavBar, incase it is needed

```
<div class="navbar">
             <a href="<?php echo base_url('Userpanel/index');?>">PROFIILI</a>
             <a href="<?php echo base_url('Userpanel/accounting');?>">LASKUTUS</a>
             <a href="<?php echo base_url('Userpanel/commissions');?>">TOIMEKSIANNOT</a>
             <a href="<?php echo base_url('Userpanel/logout');?>">KIRJAUDU ULOS</a>
</div>
```

Yet, for some reason, I keep getting error that db_error and file_error are undefined. While looking for source of this, I started using breakpoint variable to see where the issue was and it stops at "Navigointi Alku" breakpoint. Yet, everything else on the page renders correctly. It seems that after a certain point the $data variable is simply no longer updated. Everything else on the page renders correctly, but the breakpoint variable seem to stop being updated after the navbar is loaded, despite the exection of the function continuing enough to get an error page.

Any ideas what could be causing this? Everywhere else in the program these systems work fine, but when it comes to uploading images it causes trouble.

No routing has been done. I am using CodeIgniter 3.

Comment: what's the error that you are getting in logs ?

Answer (score 0):

**Some Times Upload Errors occures due to the small things 
like file_size file type try this code :**

`switch ($_FILES['file1']['error'])
{
case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
echo "File uploaded succesfuly";
break;
case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
echo "Uploaded File is too big";
break;
case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL :
echo "File is not completely uploaded";
break;
case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE :
echo "No File was Selected";
break;`

Comment: Didn't fix it. Issue is not file upload error, issue is that I can't store and show the error.